# Retrieve date fullCalenadar

Tags: jquery

Morning,
I have a fullCalendar and  I want to get the first and the last date of the week. For example:
Today is 20150925 but when I'am in other week (es. 20151012 20151018) of calendar I want to get pertaining date

Could you please help me?
Thanks

Comment: Which calendar api you are using ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the JavaScript Date object: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

There is a method `getDay()` which returns the current day of the week in the range 0 - 6. Which is convenient. Subtract the appropriate amount from the current day to get the first day of the week and add to get the last day of the week. JavaScript date arithmetic wraps, so a negative date goes to the previous month and a day larger than the number of days in the month goes to the next month.

Thus:

```
var today = new Date();
var y = today.getFullYear();
var d = today.getDate();
var m = today.getMonth();
var dow = today.getDay();
var first = new Date(y, m, d - dow);
var last = new Date(y, m, d + (6 - dow));
```